# Which door to the party?

Tags: cipher, story

As you stroll on a walk with your friend, your friend talks about moving. Your friend doesn't have enough money to move to a good apartment, so he contemplates moving to a cheap hotel, but this hotel may be haunted (if the rumors are true). You advise him not to move, but he has no choice...

A couple of months later, your friend lets you know that he's doing fine! He even is organizing a party there, and you are invited! You are quite excited. The party letter informs you of the door number and gives you one warning: "Make sure you come in the correct room. The other rooms may be haunted..."

You go to bed, excited about the party. Your party letter is on the table next to you, and your bedside window is open. During the night, at around 3:25am, you feel a ghost slithering over you, and then you hear a scraping sound. You turn around, half-asleep, open your eyes, assume it was a dream, and then go back to sleep.

The next morning, you notice that the room number has been scraped off of the party letter, and you can't remember which room to go to.

You know your friend would be REALLY disappointed if you didn't come to the party, so you decide to go anyway. You think that you'll be able to find the room anyway, it shouldn't be that hard.

When you arrive at the hotel, you see many doors leading to rooms. Each door has a room number and a label:

Room `12`: `ezmwqe`.

Room `13`: `ryrcunagf`.

Room `14`: `acbysmg`.

Room `15`: `vwdhih`.

Room `16`: `xkcqdi`.

Room `17`: `uirxfej`.

Room `18`: `sdawfk`.

Room `19`: `lihhdr infidbgl`.

You realize something, enter a room, and find your friend waiting for you!

Which room did you enter?

Hint:

> The number of the room relates to the cipher used to decrypt the labels of the rooms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize that

> the label on each room has been encoded with ROT_X, where X is the room number. You decode them all to find that the rooms are labeled as follows:
>
> - Room 12: snakes
>  - Room 13: elephants
>  - Room 14: monkeys
>  - Room 15: ghosts
>  - Room 16: humans
>  - Room 17: dragons
>  - Room 18: aliens
>  - Room 19: spooky pumpkins
>
> Having deciphered the codes, you presumably enter **room 16** (though I dunno, some of those other rooms sound like they'd make for a pretty fun party).

Comment: For halloween the last 5 rooms dont seem to bad